# No puedo usar Snippets en VSCode C#

Tags: c#, vscode

Actualmente trabajo con VSCode junto a Unity y C# hace poco actualice VSCode a su última versión y a la hora de escribir palabras reservadas de funciones como `for` o `if`, saltan las opciones de autocompletar como normalmente debe pasar sin embargo a la hora de dar <kbd>TAB</kbd> para activar el *snippet* de dicha función no se autocompleta.

Los snippets que vienen por defecto pero el primero que esta seleccionado que es el del ciclo for a dar <kbd>TAB</kbd> no hace nada, simplemente cierra ese `popup`, si escojo el de abajo y doy <kbd>TAB</kbd> entonces sí se despliega el código de dicha función, incluso en tercera posición se puede ver el *snippet* que hice para tener más comodidad a la hora de poner snippets así.

Al mismo tiempo y debajo del `for` se pueden los *snippets* del `foreach` y de nuevo el ícono que no tengo idea de qué es, pero si doy <kbd>TAB</kbd> sobre el solo cierra el *popup*.

Dicen que una imagen vale más que mil palabras:

[image: introducir la descripción del enlace aquí]

Comment: Realmente son dos TABS, uno para completar la palabra y otro para completar el segmento de código de ejemplo.

Comment: Te pongo un GIF para ejemplificar mejor el comportamiento:  
https://imgur.com/FJzOCkB

Comment: Félix, me tomé la libertad de editar tu pregunta para ejemplificar tu escenario, con esto es posible que a más de un desarrollador tenga el mismo problema y tu pregunta obtenga una mayor audiencia. Evidentemente es algo que tiene que ver con la actualización de VSCode y veré si encuentro algo por la red ya que de igual forma yo lo uso y no me gustaría tener el mismo problema :P

Comment: hay 2 for ahi.. uno con un cuadradito completo y otro con uno vacio.. yo uso vs asi que no tengo ese problema.. pero tendra que ver con eso?

Comment: @gbianchi es correcto, lo que logro entender es que así se puso desde la actualización del VSCode. El primero sería de "escritura libre" por el `ABC` que aparece en el cuadrito de la izquierda, el otro sería la sugerencia del snippet

Comment: Prueba con cambiar la propiedad `editor.snippetSuggestions` a `top`, eso va a poner los snippets por encima de los nombres y palabras que hayas utilizado en tu código, pero al darle tab dos veces, debería funcionar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema se debe a que la configuración del autocompletado se encuentra desactivada, por *default* viene `"editor.tabCompletion": false`.

Para cambiar esta configuración, debes hacer lo siguiente:

1. Menú `File -->  Preferences --> Settings`.
2. Buscar la propiedad `"editor.tabCompletion"` y cambiar el valor a `true`.
3. Si te es complicado buscar la propiedad puedes hacer uso de la barra de búsqueda superior, o en su caso, en la parte de la derecha aparece la sección **`UserSettings`** y puedes escribir lo siguiente:

   ```
   {
       "editor.tabCompletion": true
   }
   ```

Ambos ajustes obtienen el mismo resultado.

La documentación oficial la puedes encontrar en [la siguiente liga](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets) <sup>en inglés</sup>.

Comment: Muchísimo mejor!!

Comment: Madre mia, por fin. Muchas gracias, honestamente me volvia loco esta configuración y tener que estar creando snippets para todo.